# Animation not restarting on key down in JavaScript Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, oop, animation, canvas

I'm creating a webpage which performs a different animation for each key that is pressed down on the keyboard. Trouble is after the animation has run once, the shape that is on screen will just flicker and will not restart over and perform the animation again. Any help will be appreciated. 
Below is the code I am using

```
//Creates a new set for objects to be stored in
const animationAObjects = new Set();
// Creating the rectangle and setting the animation properties of the rectangle
let animationARect = new Rectangle(context,canvas.width/1.5,canvas.height/2, randomColour(), "transparent", 0, new Map() ,50,50);

animationARect.deltas.set("y",100);
animationARect.deltas.set("height",50);
animationARect.deltas.set("width",50);
animationARect.deltas.set("x",100);
animationARect.limits.max.set("y", canvas.height/2);
animationARect.limits.max.set("x", canvas.width/2.5);
animationARect.limits.max.set("height",randomBetween(100,170));
animationARect.limits.max.set("width",randomBetween(100,170));

animationAObjects.add(animationARect);
// Grabs current time
let lastTime = Date.now();
var requestId;
let movementPerSecond = 300;

// Animates all of the objects in the selected set
// Animates all of the objects in the selected set
function animationA(){
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    const diffSeconds = (Date.now() - lastTime) / 1000;
    lastTime = Date.now();


  if(diffSeconds > 0){
    for(const animationAObject of animationAObjects){
        animationAObject.applyAnimation(diffSeconds);
        animationAObject.draw();

    }
}
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
cancelAnimationFrame(requestId);
if(e.keyCode == 65){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animationA);
} 
});
```

Comment: Do you remember to set `lastTime` to `Date.now()` before running `animationA`?

Comment: @user1421750 Yes I forgot to include this in, but I did declare that before I ran the function. I'll add it into an edit now.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't stop running the first "instance" of `animationA` before you start the next one. `animationA` will keep calling `requestAnimationFrame` without a termination condition, so after attempting to reset you will in have two concurrent instances attempting to draw to your canvas.

Comment: @user1421750 - Do you have any idea how I go about resolving this and stop running the requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: Make a global variable, `requestId`. Then change `requestAnimationFrame(animationA)` to `requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationA)` in `animationA`. When resetting the animation, do `cancelAnimationFrame(requestId)` before restarting it.

Comment: @user1421750 This has solved the flashing problem that I had, but the shapes still do not reset to their original position and start the animation again when I press the key again, instead they just stay there. Any ideas why they might be doing this ?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your post.

Comment: @user1421750 Iv'e added a few more comments and removed some unnecessary code, but that is pretty much all of the important code that is needed for this problem.

Comment: It's too little information. This code doesn't show how you are calling `animationA` or how you are attempting to perform a restart, nor does it reflect how you implemented the latest changes I suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127135/discussion-between-seanrs97-and-user1421750).

Comment: @user1421750 My apologies, I have edited the above code again, I hope this explains what is happening, a bit better.

Comment: @user1421750 It appears my last edit didn't clarify much so I have added all of my code above.